# css not working inside div of contentPlaceHolder in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a aspx page which is inheriting the master page.So the content in this page are kept inside contentplaceholder.The content has a div say div1 which inturn has two more div say div2 and div3 inside It.When i applay style to the div1 it works but for div2 and div3 it dosen't.

When i use firebug,the style sheet shows only the div id of div1.But i do have div2 and div3 as well.

Here's the code.

```asp
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="adminCPH1" Runat="Server">
<link href="../Styles/adminStyl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="div1">
   <div id="div2">
     I am div2 inside div1
   </div>

  <div id ="div3">
    I am div3 inside div1
  </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is the stylesheet:

```css
#div1
{
    background-color:red;
    width:300px;
    height:200px
}

#div2
{
    background-color:green;
    width:100px;
    height:200px
}

#div3
{
    background-color:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:200px
}
```

**EDIT**

This thing is now working.After trying everything two days ago,I left the code as it is and when I ran the program two days after its working good.But when i make the change in css it's still not working.
I use the firebug and now this shows all the divs I have created.I make change from the firebug,it works.I make change in the original file,nothing change.I don't know what is going on.I guess it will work once again after I restart my PC.

Comment: is changed your "div2" and "div3" after running in browser? check it plz and answer, thank you

Comment: I dind't catch you..what do you mean?

Comment: in firebug, what's the id of "div2" and "div3"?

Comment: It's div2 and div3..no change.

Comment: Is there a closing tag for the contentplaceholder?

Comment: Sorry about that..yes it has closing tag

Comment: A page does not inherit from a master page. How did you create the content page? Using the VS GUI or did you wire it by hand?

Comment: Why are you linking to the stylesheet in the content page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your CSS file is being cached... which is the normal and desired behaviour.

Your options are, after making the update, when displaying in the browser hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to flush the browser cache for the page.

Your other option is to add a cache breaker to the CSS reference after making the change.

```
<link href="../Styles/adminStyl.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Change the value after `v` when you make changes.

Answer (score 0):

please try this steps:

1. add a contentPlaecHolder in  of your master page
2. add its content section in your page
3. add your stylesheet defination inside it
4. check...

   ```
   <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" Runat="Server">
         <link href="../Styles/adminStyl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </asp:Content>
   ```

if it works  problem solved ;) but if not try styling your div's inside html such as

hope this was helpful

Comment: contentplaceholder is ofcourse in the masterpage otherwise how will i be able to use content in aspx page.Every thing you have mentioned is already tested and done.If i put the css inline it works however.But i neeed it in sepeate file in stylesheet.

Comment: Then it's the link to the CSS file from the master page that is wrong - this is a known bug.

Comment: But the css works for the DIV inside the content place holder.If there is a div inside that div then in that case it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Remove the CSS tag from where you have it now. Then drag the stylesheet from solution explorer to the head section in the master page in code view.

Comment: Did you re-compile and empty browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

ok,you should use method(change and test).and what is this method?change and test until find the solution
and now

please replace div id's with together and check it work or not and whats the result..

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="adminCPH1" Runat="Server">
<link href="../Styles/adminStyl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="div3">
   <div id="div2">
     I am div2 inside div1
   </div>

  <div id ="div1">
    I am div3 inside div1
  </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

or

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="adminCPH1" Runat="Server">
<link href="../Styles/adminStyl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="div2">
   <div id="div3">
     I am div2 inside div1
   </div>

  <div id ="div1">
    I am div3 inside div1
  </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

show your result to us.

thank you